# Extract text form RichTextBox in Windows store metro app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, richtextbox, flowdocument, textrange

I am developing Windows Store App. I used a `RichTextBox` but could not get text from it, I've searched in internet an tried with `TextRange`, `FlowDocument` etc. But none of its working. Any idea how to get text form  RichTextBox on a submit button click?

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN, `RichTextBox.Document` property gets an object that enables access to the text contained in the RichEditBox.

It returns a `ITextDocument` which have a [`GetText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.text.itextdocument.gettext.aspx) property.

To get the text, you would have to do:

```
var text = String.Empty;
richTextBox.Document.GetText(TextGetOptions.None, out text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the full plain text of a FlowDocument hosted in a WPF-RichTextBox:

```
string fullPlainText = new TextRange(richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
```